# Use Supabase with deno

Tags: database, deno, supabase

I'm trying to use Supabase with deno.
I used `import { createClient } from "https://esm.sh/@supabase/supabase-js"` but it only gives me errors like
`Module '"deno:///missing_dependency.d.ts"' uses 'export =' and cannot be used with 'export *'`

Comment: try to import from this url for [deno supabase](https://deno.land/x/supabase@1.1.0): https://deno.land/x/supabase/mod.ts

Comment: Already saw that, but it throws an error too; I think it's outdatet not only because it's about 150 Commits behind supabase.
Error: error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'href')
  if (!url) url = window.location.href

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved: Used `import { createClient } from "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@supabase/supabase-js/+esm"`

Comment: It fixes the error, but in you lose the type definitions with this file

Comment: It's worth noting that the official docs recommend to use `esm.sh`:

`import { createClient } from 'https://esm.sh/@supabase/supabase-js@2'`

Answer (score 2):

Using the [Supabase Deno](https://deno.land/x/supabase_deno@v1.0.5) package works for me.

```
import { supabaseClient } from "https://deno.land/x/supabase_deno/mod.ts";
const sbclient = new supabaseClient("https://xyz.supabase.co","your-anon-key")
const sbTableItems = new supabaseTableItems(sbclient, "your-table");
const result = await sbTableItems.add(data);
```

Comment: Thanks, but that's literally my own code, I tried to do it on my own 